# Java based Telnet Application

Tags: java, telnet

I want to create Java based Telnet application which can send the telnet command to some server and capture it response , in simply command line Telnet emulator,
Please kindly provide some tutorial to create.

i saw couple of tutorial it required java telnet server and client both , but my case i need only need send command and capture telnet output to variable or  write text file

Thank you.

Comment: Too broad. There are a dozen or more applicable RFCs, and several extant implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Apache Commons Net [TelnetClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/telnet/TelnetClientExample.java). It could easily provide the behaviuor you need. You just have to get the `TelnetClient` instance, call the `connect` method and work with remote server via Input- and OutputStreams. [Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/telnet/TelnetClientExample.java) you can find an official example, how it can be used, but it's a little bit redundant, IMO.

Here is one more example from [here](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/12/22/java-writing-an-automated-telnet-client/):

```
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class AutomatedTelnetClient {
    private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
    private InputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;
    private String prompt = "%";

    public AutomatedTelnetClient(String server, String user, String password) {
        try {
            // Connect to the specified server
            telnet.connect(server, 23);

            // Get input and output stream references
            in = telnet.getInputStream();
            out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());

            // Log the user on
            readUntil("login: ");
            write(user);
            readUntil("Password: ");
            write(password);

            // Advance to a prompt
            readUntil(prompt + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void su(String password) {
        try {
            write("su");
            readUntil("Password: ");
            write(password);
            prompt = "#";
            readUntil(prompt + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readUntil(String pattern) {
        try {
            char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            boolean found = false;
            char ch = (char) in.read();
            while (true) {
                System.out.print(ch);
                sb.append(ch);
                if (ch == lastChar) {
                    if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
                        return sb.toString();
                    }
                }
                ch = (char) in.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void write(String value) {
        try {
            out.println(value);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String sendCommand(String command) {
        try {
            write(command);
            return readUntil(prompt + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            telnet.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient(
                    "myserver", "userId", "Password");
            System.out.println("Got Connection...");
            telnet.sendCommand("ps -ef ");
            System.out.println("run command");
            telnet.sendCommand("ls ");
            System.out.println("run command 2");
            telnet.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked :)